# java Kendo UI grid how to access model fields

Tags: java, kendo-ui-mvc

I am displaying Kendo UI grid in a JSP page . Here is the code . I have designed a webservice for the create method . The method is getting called . But I could not able to access the model fields . Means I want to access the fields values of the selected row , to insert it into database. How can I access it ? .

```
<div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8081/app/personcontacttypes",
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/getAll",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/update",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/delete",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Create",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                             parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                             }
                    },
                    batch: true,
                    pageSize: 20,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "personContactId",
                            fields: {
                                personContactId: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                dropDown: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                                formattedAppearnce: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                                fullDefination: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                                notes: { editable: true, nullable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                        columns: [
                            { field: "formattedAppearnce", title: "Formatted Appearance", format: "{0:c}", width: 140 },
                             { field: "dropDown", title: "Drop Down", format: "{0:c}", width: 140 },
                            { field: "fullDefination", title: "Full Defination", width: 140 },
                            { field: "notes", width: 190 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 50 }],
                        editable: true
                    });
                });             

        </script>           
    </div>
```